# Javascript hide div (is:empty) issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have some code to hide a div, if it's contents are empty. This SHOULD work...its' worked before. Am I missing something obvious here? The div class = "msgalert"

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('.msgalert').is(':empty')) {
        $(".msgalert").css({'display':'none'});
    }
});
```

The corresponding CSS is:

```
.msgalert { border: 1px solid #eac572; background-color: #ffe9ad; }
```

Please help! Thanks :)

Comment: Does `$(".msgalert:empty").css({'display':'none'});` work?

Comment: `:empty` means absolutely no content, including whitespace, so make sure the elements are actually empty.

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/jSYC3/

Comment: Doesnt work...here is my version! http://jsfiddle.net/jSYC3/2/

Comment: Of course it doesn't work. You included HTML tags in the JavaScript. http://jsfiddle.net/jSYC3/5/ So was the actual issue that you had whitespace inside the element, as I see you do in the demo?

Answer (score 3):

Try checking if the length of the `html()` of `.msgalert` is 0 instead of checking if it's `:empty`, like this:

```
if ($.trim($('.msgalert').html()).length == 0) {
```

You'll want to trim the `html()` to account for the whitespace as well.

Comment: I like this instead of `:empty` selector +1

Comment: Why would this provide a different result from `:empty`?

Comment: `text()` doesn't take into account whitespace, I believe. Making a fiddle to test it now...

Comment: It does. Whitespace is text too. ;) You need to `$.trim` it to see if it's whitespace only.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville What about this case `<div class="msgalert"​><br/></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`...Is it 'empty' at all?

Comment: @Engineer: `text()` strips out HTML elements.

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity: Funny, I was just testing `$.trim`. Heh.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville Yeah, I know it. But 'empty' means `'no content'`, no tags, no text.

Comment: @Engineer: Precisely. Because `.text()` strips out HTML, the `<br/>` will get stripped out too and won't count towards the length. If you want to ignore whitespace, you can use `$.trim`, as **cliffsofinsanity** pointed out.

Comment: @Engineer is right. Ignoring elements doesn't mean they're not there. The `.text()` method doesn't remove them. It simply won't test for their existence.

Comment: Ah, I see what he was saying now. Well, I'd suggest taking a look at Vega's answer, then. He does it right.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: His doesn't test for whitespace either. All you really need to do is use `$.trim` with `.html()` instead of `.text()`, or just use `:empty`.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville I make `<br/>` tag to illustrate the problem. I could use `<div class="msgalert"​><div></div></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​` either and the result will be wrong again.

Comment: Move the `)` to the left of `.length`. `if ($.trim($('.msgalert').html()).length == 0) {`

Comment: Oh, woops, right. Thanks for the catch (what is that now, third mistake you find in my answer? Ha). :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just posting my version,

```
$('.msgalert').filter(function () {
   return ($(this).text().length == 0 && $(this).children().length == 0);
}).css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: included `.children` check for empty tags :)

Comment: @casey7398 Your fiddle was buggy.. try here http://jsfiddle.net/skram/jSYC3/4/  --> btw.. you were trying out Elliot suggestion.

Comment: Does it not working have anything to do with <div class=msgalert> being inside of another div id....?